# посчитать через протокол UDP количество потерянных пакетов

Tags: c#, udp

Вообще не понимаю как можно считать дейтаграммы, так как в этом коде все сообщения доходят до получателя
и numberOfSentBytes всегда равно количеству принятых байт.
и не нашел в классе UdpClient ничего что могло было бы связанно с отправкой дейтаграмм и потерей пакетов
...

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(8001);
string message = "Hello world!";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
int numberOfSentBytes = client.Send(data, data.Length);
```

...

Comment: UDP - это отправка в один конец без подтверждения, без гарантии целостности и без гарантии получения. Хотите исключать потери - используйте TCP. Либо отправляйте от получателя подтверждение получения, но по сути получится тот же TCP.

Comment: TCP на самом деле так же не гарантирует коректного подтверждения о получении если что...) Гугл в помощь.  Но для средней ситуации TCP достаточно, конечно же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контроль доставки в UDP отсутствует в протоколе. Все контроллирующие функции вы можете реализовать только своими силами.

Например вы можете нумеровать пакеты при передаче. 1,2,3,4,5... и с другой стороны то же самое. При чем в первом пакете можно указать количество передаваемых. Если вдруг получена последовательность 1,3,2,5 из 5. То значит 4 пакет потерялся, и можно попросить отправить его снова.

Да, кстати, порядок получения пакетов во времени может отличаться от порядка отправки, здесь тоже у UDP нет никаких гарантий.

Ну это я самый примитивный случай предположил. Прелесть отсутствия стандарта контроля доставки здесь в том, что у вас полная свобода творчества. Можно не только пакеты считать можно их заведомо отправлять в 2 раза больше, дублируя все данные дважды. Тогда потерей одного пакета можно будет вообще пренебречь. Я так эти идеи могу вечно генерировать.

Comment: нумеровать пакеты, это к примеру в тексте пакета приписывать номера, как например "сообщение 1" "сообщение 2" и т.д?

Comment: @wildober содержимое датаграммы вы тоже определяете сами. Представьте простой массив байт, что в него запишете, то и улетит в сеть. В виде байт можно представить не только текст, а вообще что угодно.